# How to run coded ui script multiple times for performance driven test

Tags: performance-testing, coded-ui-tests

I want to run the coded UI data driven script for 7days. Is that possible?

I am running for performance testing a desktop based application.

I am using Datasource as an XML file:

```
      <Env> 
            <Nav>
              <Path1>a</Path1>
              <Path2>b</Path2>
              <Path3>c</Path3>
              <Path4>d</Path4>
           </Nav>
           <Nav>
             <Path1>e</Path1>
             <Path2>f</Path2>
             <Path3>g</Path3>
             <Path4>h</Path4>
          </Nav>
      </Env>
```

My script navigates to path abcd, then efgh and then it stops.
I want that my script should continue to run to abcd again after efgh untill I stop it manually. Can I do that using coded UI ? and How?

Comment: Related question, non-duplicative: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962809/coded-ui-test-c-manual-intervention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962809/coded-ui-test-c-manual-intervention)

Comment: Thanks for the Link, But I am not looking for manual intervention. My question is is it possible to run the test continuously without manual intervention  in infinite loop in coded UI? I want my script to execute , once it finishes execution, I want it to wait for 15 minutes and re execute again automatically

Comment: How are you running the test? If the test is executed with `mstest.exe` or similar then you could call that command from a loop within a batch script.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I am simply doing a right click in the Test explorer to run my test.

Comment: I will try to run it using mstest.exe

Comment: @AdrianHHH   I tried to find mstest.exe, but did not get it. I am new to codedUI, Where can I find mstest.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a simple GoTo to your `[TestMethod]` to keep running the same steps over and over:

```
[DeploymentItem("ProjectName\\Data.xml"), TestMethod()]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML",
               "|DataDirectory|\\Data.xml",
               "Row",
                DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
public void Test()
{
     Start:
     DoStuff();
     goto Start;
}
```

It's a dirty solution, but this should run until you manually stop it.

Comment: How will this method cause the values from the data source to be read again and again? This approach will read the first set of data and use it repeatedly.

Comment: Hi Thomas Bouman, thanks for your reply! But I agree with AdrianHHH, it reads the first set of data and use it repeatedly, I want to read all the data sets from datasource and then repeat the loop.

Comment: I can use Thomas Bouman's solution , if I tweak my xml structure to<ENV> <NAV><Path1>a,e</Path1><Path2>b,f</Path2><Path3>c,g</Path3><Path4>d,h</Path4></NAV></ENV>                                                      I store the value of PathX in an an array by using split function on ','